# Prevent to access internet by specific program if it is not connected to OpenVPN servef

Tags: windows, openvpn

I've looked over the Internet and haven't found any solution. My task is to prevent access to the Internet by Google Chrome if the system is not running an OpenVPN connection. So, as the result it will:

1. Block Internet access if OpenVPN is not connected.
2. Allow Internet access if OpenVPN is connected.

Any ideas? The platform is **Windows 10**. With other types of VPN connections, it was possible to stick to the specific interface and to configure Windows Firewall. The target machine is remote one and is manipulated by TeamViewer so the best case is to block only Google Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a workaround. You need to switch your main network to Private profile. When you connect through OpenVPN your system works in Public profile. Thus you can configure the firewall to allow connections only through the Public profile. I this case, when Google Chrome runs through Private profile it will not allow the connection.